# Slide exit animation from activity_1 to activity_2

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, slide

Does anybody know how can I implement this animation ?

Explication of my animation :

1. I click on Bloc A or B in Activity_1
2. Bloc A slide completly to top and Bloc B slide completly to bottom
3. During the animation, we can already see what's inside Activity_2
4. We are in Activity_2

[image: Slide animation I want]

I've read that there is Slide Animation when we exit Activity with Android Lollipop. 
I tried to implement it like that but it doesn't worked :

```
      bloc_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_1.this, Activity_2.class);

            Slide topTransition = new Slide();
            topTransition.addTarget(bloc_a);
            topTransition.setSlideEdge(Gravity.TOP);
            topTransition.setDuration(10000);
            getWindow().setExitTransition(topTransition);

            Slide bottomTransition = new Slide();
            bottomTransition.addTarget(bloc_b);
            bottomTransition.setSlideEdge(Gravity.TOP);
            bottomTransition.setDuration(10000);
            getWindow().setExitTransition(bottomTransition);

            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity_1.this);
            startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Comment: @Shailesh I've already checked it but it did'nt work